# gnu screen - changing the default escape command key to ALT-X?

Tags: emacs, gnu, gnu-screen, screenrc

In GNU screen, I want to change the default command binding to Alt-s (by tweaking .screenrc) instead of the default C-a, the reason is I use emacs hence GNU screen binds the C-a key, sending "C-a" to the emacs becomes tedious (as @Nils said, to send "C-a" I should type "C-a a"), as well as "C-a" in bash shell, and I could change the escape to C- but some of them are already mapped in emacs and other combinations are not as easy as ALT-s . If anyone has already done a ALT key mapping, please do let me know.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to work around *:escape* command limitations using *registers* and *:bindkey* command. Just put this in *.screenrc*:

```
# reset escape key to the default
escape ^Aa

# auxiliary register
register S ^A

# Alt + x produces ^A and acts as an escape key
bindkey "^[x" process S

## Alt + space produces ^A and acts as an escape key
# bindkey "^[ " process S
```

See http://adb.cba.pl/gnu-screen-tips-page-my.html#howto-alt-key-as-escape

Answer (score 10):

From my reading of `man screen` it seems like the only meta character that `screen` can use for the command binding is `CTRL`:

```
   escape xy

   Set  the  command character to x and the character generating a literal
   command character (by triggering the "meta" command) to y (similar to
   the -e option).  Each argument is either a single character, a two-character
   sequence of the form "^x" (meaning "C-x"), a backslash followed by an octal
   number (specifying the ASCII code of the character),  or a backslash followed
   by a second character, such as "\^" or "\\".  The default is "^Aa".
```

If there is some mapping that you don't use in emacs, even if it's inconvenient, like `C-|`, then you could use your terminal input manager to remap `ALT-X` to that, letting you use the `ALT` binding instead.  That would be a little hackish though.

Comment: thanks. That's sort of tricky, perhaps there could be a direct way to do this

Comment: You don't have to preface the escape key with Control. I use "escape `~", which sets the it to backtick (without Control). I don't think you can use Alt-anything, though.

Comment: @silentbicyle thanks. yeah i know I dont have to preface with Control, "escape `~" doesn't work for me. And I ll become tedious when I have to actually ~ in any of the programs running on the shell, that is the reason why I prefer CTL/ALT mapping.

Comment: See my answer below. The "escape" command uses so-called caret notation. So you use ^G for G as the control character. The tricky part is that "escape" expects two concatenated arguments: the "controlling character" (a by default) and a meta character ([ by default)

Answer (score 10):

I'm an Emacs and screen user as well.  Although I rarely use Emacs in a terminal -- and as such in a screen session -- I didn't want to give up C-a for the shell either (which uses Emacs key bindings).  My solution was to use C-j as the prefix key for screen, which I was willing to sacrifice.  In Emacs programming modes it is bound to (newline-and-indent) which I bound to RET as well, so I really don't miss it.

By the way: I know this is an advise rather than an answer, but I felt this would be valuable enough to post nevertheless.

Answer (score 8):

To make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> the default prefix for commands and free C-a, add the following lines to .screenrc:

```
escape ^||
bindkey "^[x" command
```

As a side effect C-| will be command prefix too. If you need this keys to be free too, then fix "escape ^||"  accordingly.

Comment: How does `^[x` be transfered to `Alt-x`, where `^` means `Ctrl`(I'm not sure)? Does `[` mean `Alt`? Thanks.

Comment: If you are blessed with an `Alt Gr` key (in, for example, a Latin American keyboard), you can take advantage of it as third level modifier to input a rarely used symbol which you can bind as command key.  For example, with my LA keyboard in Ubuntu, I have `bindkey "ð" command` in .screenrc.  So, I use `Alt Gr + d` (which sends the ð character) as my command key.

Answer (score 7):

Screen doesn't have any shorthand syntax for alt bindings, but you can give it the octal code directly. For instance on my machine, Alt-x has the hex code F8, or 370 octal, so putting

escape \370x

in my screenrc changed the escape code to alt-X

Tested and works with screen 4.00.03 on Linux.

You may have to change the escape, since I think this may depend on things like your language and codeset, etc: how I found out what my escape code was was to type

```
$ echo -n ^QM-x | perl -ne 'printf "%lo\n", ord($_)'
```

^Q is the quoted-insert command for readline (it inserts what you type directly without trying to interpret it) and M-x was a literal Alt-X.

Comment: I have tried this trick and it doesn't work for me. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Hi Siva - I think the most likely difference is due to the terminal encoding of the meta keys. I'm using xterm with the xterm termcap/terminfo setting; it's possible other terminals like kterm or gnome-terminal, or different TERM settings, use a different encoding. What does my echo trick produce on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Something I have had for years in my `.screenrc`:

```
escape ^Zz
```

which is now hardwired in muscle memory for me.

Somehow I ended up having to share a screen with someone else's config, and now I keep stopping processes all the time (bash `^Z`)... Not funny...

Answer (score 0):

Fellow emacs user here.

The best solution I've found is a ~/.screenrc file with the following:

```
# C-a :source .screenrc

escape ^gg
```

Live updated here: https://gist.github.com/1058111

See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=498675

Comment: btw, this works really well for me because ^G is the "cancel" sequence in emacs. So if your muscle memory 'spasms', you don't mess anything up in emacs.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this. C-g is one of the last keys I would want to give up in Emacs.

Comment: Change it to "escape ^\`[" to use backquote. C-\` is not bound to anything in Emacs by default.